# CriteriaDAO only initializing lazy collection when @Transactional is added to the method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

**Summary**

I have a method that uses a Session object to build a criteriaBuilder and then fetch an Object called Document (Document). This object has two 'one-to-many' lists. I want to initialize them.
Even while the session is open, it refuses to initialize the two lists giving "Session could not initialize proxy - no Session" at line: Hibernate.initialize(singleResult.getRevisoes());

---

**Proposed Solution**

Adding `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)` to the method signature, solves the issue. However, does that opens a new connection? Am I wasting resources? Is there a better way to tackle this issue?

---

```
@Autowired
protected Session session;

....

@Override
public Document find(Long id, boolean close) {
    try {
        
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

        CriteriaQuery<Document> queryDocument = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Document.class);

        Root<Document> rootDocument = queryDocument.from(Document.class);


        queryDocument.select(rootDocument);
        queryDocument.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(rootDocument.get("id"), id));

        TypedQuery<Document> query = session.createQuery(queryDocument);

        Document singleResult = query.getSingleResult();

        System.out.println(session.isOpen()); //Returns true
        
        //Initialize other lists (one to many)
        Hibernate.initialize(singleResult.getRevisions());
        Hibernate.initialize(singleResult.getFiles());

        //
        return singleResult;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (session != null && close) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**References**

https://codete.com/blog/spring-transaction-propagation-modes

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/annotations.html#transaction-declarative-annotations-method-visibility

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/tx-propagation.html

Comment: you almost always want to be working with a hibernate session within a transaction.  is there a reason you _don't_ want to be using a transaction?

Comment: Im afraid it will spend another connection from the datasource.

Comment: if you have configured hibernate correctly, the session should be associated with the transaction.

Comment: I dont know if I configured hibernate correctly. Any tips?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/orm/hibernate.html

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-spring

Comment: What makes you think the Session is open?

Comment: System.out.println(session.isOpen()); //Returns true

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are getting the 'No session' here because I haven't used this style of criteria building much. But using @Transactional shouldn't any performance issues. Think of @Transactional like instructing it to create a database session at the beginning of the method and committing and closing it at the end of the method. You can even get rid of the `REQUIRED` type because it is the default type.

I think the best alternative would be to use a join fetch type of a query to load all at once if that suits you.

Answer (score 1):

The session is bound to the transaction. Within one session you can have multiple transactions. At least one transaction should be active for the session to exist.

On the other hand the transaction does not have anything to do with the connection to your database, but the underlying connection pool or the driver has.